Sieve Method works for variant question?
There are multiple results on the sieve method, and I wanted to ask about the following variant
(to know if it is trivial by one of the current versions of the sieve method, or seems a challenging problem)
Let $\varepsilon>0$ be fixed.
Then there exists $0<\delta<\varepsilon$, such that for all sufficiently large $k$ the following is true.
Let the primes strictly between $\sqrt k$ and $k$ be written as $\sqrt k <p_1\le  \ldots \le p_r <k$. Let $M= \prod_{i=1}^j p_j$.
For every $1 \le j \le r$,
let $I_j= \left \{1,2,\ldots, \left \lceil p_j^{1-\delta} \right \rceil \right \}$.
Then among every $M^\varepsilon$ consecutive integers,
there is at least one value $x$ for which
$ x \bmod p_j$ belongs to $I_j$ for every $1 \le j \le r$.
Note: By the prime number theorem, $M=k^{\Theta( k/ \log{k} )}$.
The average size of intersection is at least $M^{\varepsilon-\delta}$, which is large for $k$ large. One can e.g. assume $(\varepsilon-\delta) k^{0.01}> \log{k}$.
So maybe this is easy for the experts.
Thanks in advance.
ps: if the problem is solved, with almost all k instead of all k, I would also be happy. But then the proof may use different ideas.

what does "choose intervals $I_j$ with the first $p_j^{1-\delta}$ numbers" mean?

You need to define $I_j$ and $M$ more explicitly. The way it's currently written the question is hard to parse.

@AlexeiEntin I believe that $M=\prod_{j=1}^r p_j$, so probably $M$ is the product of the primes in $[\sqrt{k},k]$. Also, I believe that $I_j=\mathbb{N}\cap[1,p_j^{1-\delta}]$.

The above (reply by GH) is correct. Should have written first $p_j^{1-\delta}$ natural numbers to be clearer.
Alternatively, one can also aim more general; for every $I_j\subset [p_j]$ for which $\vert I_j \rvert = p_j^{1-\delta}$.

My issue is that the phrase "choose intervals $I_j$ with the first $p_j^{1-\delta}$ (natural) numbers" is not correct English, specifically the word "with".

Question has been edited to clarify all the issues.

As an update; it is now part of https://arxiv.org/pdf/2410.09138
